# Validation problem with editText and a RadioGroup

Tags: java, android

I have an editText and a radioGroup.
How to delete the content of an editText when selecting a radioButton in the radioGroup and reverse deselect the radioButton when typing in the editText

Comment: You need listeners to handle your condition. Try searching with edittext change listener and radio group selection change listener. Inside those listener you need to write your condition.

Comment: How to do that: can you give mr a exemple